# How can someone log command line input using php?

Tags: php

One of my company's servers was recently hacked into. As I am sifting through files, I have noticed that my command line input is being logged into a PHP file. How is this possible?

Currently, everything is being logged to a single php file.
In this log is my entire history of terminal commands since logging into the server via SSH.

For instance:

```
Last login: Thu Jan 16 16:21:17 on xxxxx
$ cd ..
$ ls -al
drwxrwxr-x+ 55 root      admin     1870 Jan 13 13:52 XXXXX
drwxr-xr-x+ 63 root      admin     2142 Nov 26 09:06 XXXX
drwxr-xr-x@  2 root      admin       68 Aug 16  2012 XXXXX
drwxr-xr-x+  4 root      admin      136 Mar 12  2013 System
```

This is being logged at the top of a php file. At the bottom of the file is a substantial amount of compressed and variable masked code.

There doesn't appear to be an eval() or shell_exec() like i expected.

Comment: Just double-checking: It's being logged *into* a php file? As in there's a php script out there, say, `foo.php`, and what you type is ending up in that file to be output to some secret webserver?

Comment: This needs way more context and info. What is getting logged where? How do you know this, can you make an example of something you are inputting (where, in a SSH shell?) and how it is coming out in the PHP script? How are you viewing the PHP scripts?

Comment: It is in fact being logged into a php file.

Comment: Made some quick updates, hopefully that adds some clarity!

Comment: How? Likely a rootkit.

Comment: **Don't expect anything!!!** What if the function that logs this data is base64 encoded and is turned into a function at run-time (like that code at the end of the file, perhaps). I bring that up because it's happened to me and is a great way to hide your malign code. If you are worried about `eval()` and `shell_exec()` then you should disable them.

Answer (score 1):

1. Save a disk image if you're concerned about forensic analysis
2. Nuke everything back down to bare metal
3. Rebuild your server and pull fresh code out of your version control
4. Change all your passwords and secure anything that may have been exposed.

Comment: This is something we're definitely doing

Comment: -1 this is not an attempt to answer the question asked.